# Reliable source for Chinese translation of Pali Canon Jataka tales (佛传故事/佛傳故事)?

Tags: translation, resources

Slightly different sort of question for everyone today, hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to do research on the Buddhist [Jataka tales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jataka_tales), originally written in the [Pali Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81li_Canon). I've been able to find many reliable translations of the Jataka tales in English, but would like to strengthen my research by drawing upon Chinese texts as well. As far as I can tell, the Jataka tales are called "佛传故事" in Chinese. I'm far from an expert at navigating the Chinese web, but what I'd ideally like to find is a PDF translation (preferably in simplified, but I'll take whatever I can get) issued by a Chinese university or museum of this text.

I know this is a long-shot, but if anyone could help me find this resource it would be much appreciated.

Comment: ＃３ of search for 佛传故事 http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_418bc36f0101et2b.html
not PDF but simplified  (rejected  by  OP?)

Answer (score 1):

It is called 本生故事 in Chinese. PDF is available here:

http://vdisk.weibo.com/s/t0ojS8AH__rfZ